# Check if data is updated in previous screen ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have multiscreen app say screen1 to screen8. Each screen has some text field and other controls to capture data. Also each screen contains the instance of a singleton object to capture data and save to DB. Now when the user moves to screen8 and again goes back to previous screen and updates and data i have to toggle a switch on the last screen.

I tried copying the object on screen8 (viewwilldisapper ) and comparing it. but no luck.

I cannot create instances on appdelegate.
what could be the best approach.

Comment: Use **NSNotificationCenter** or Custom Delegate.

Comment: in your `viewWillAppear` it should check the db and decide whether the switch is on or off

Comment: @Virussmca looks NSNotificationCenter is not a appropriate way to do the same. It would be KVO as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be stored in a model and each of the view controllers should be actioning changes on that model. As required, each view controller should be:

1. Analysing the model when their view is shown to update the view display
2. Observing changes to the model (preferably via KVO, fetched results controller or change notifications) so that the display can be updated as a reaction to changes

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah i googled on KVO and it's perfectly the one i was looking for. But the pain is i will have to do a lot of refactor for the code to make it KVC in all the screen. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 0):

initially I would make it a comment but it is too long so:

well , seems like all ur 8 screens are always "alive" so there is 2 easy ways to make the update of the content

simpliest of the 2 is to make an update in `viewWillAppear` to make a data refresh.
it will toggle each time u entering the view.
or you can use a delegate , so once the data is changed you are updating all the views who implementing the delegate no matter if they are on the screen or not.